# Как убрать ActionBar у Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как убрать `ActionBar` (черную полосу сверху, как на фото) y `Fragment'a`, чтобы остался только `layout` разметка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не экшенбар а заголовок диалога

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать заголовок диалога](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457411/177345)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать toolbar и отказываться от использования стандартного actionBar. Это Намного проще и современнее.

Comment: Мне нужно вообще убрать любой ``bar``.