# Как убрать заголовок диалога

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Как вызвать что-нибудь диалоговое без `ActionBar`, чтобы высвечивался только `layout` файл. Варианты со скрытием\убийством `ActionBar`\изменением темы `Activity```DialogFragment`` (если можно) тоже подойдут.

Попытки, которые я пробовал, но ничего не вышло:

- Сделать `Activity` с темами `@android:style/Theme.Dialog.NoTitleBar` и `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Dialog`.
- Сделать `Activity` с темами `@android:style/Theme.Dialog.NoTitleBar` и `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Dialog`.
  Сделать `DialogFragment`, а потом убрать, скрыть `ActionBar` — оказывается у `DialogFragment` нет `ActionBar` (по крайней мере, `getActionBar` не рработает).
- Сделать свой `style` с `Dialog` и `NoTitleBar`. Тут совсем ничего не вышло.

**Помогите, пожалуйста!**

Comment: Наверное не `ActionBar`, а заголовок диалога? Там, где выводится `title` ... Он к экшенбару не имеет никакого отношения и соответственно темы эту проблему никак не решат.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов решения Вашей задачи:

- Если используете `Dialog`:

  ```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_la);
  dialog.show();
  ```
- Если расширяете `DialogFragment`, то в `onCreate` добавьте следующую
  строку:

  ```
  setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
  ```

Comment: ``setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);`` не работает. Сейчас пойду переписываться под ``Dialog``...

Comment: @bukashka101 очень странно, у себя таким способом как раз и вывожу диалог без тайтла...добавляли строчку именно в `onCreate `?

Comment: Ну да. Только не в ``onCreate``, a в ``onCreateView``. У диалогов вроде же нет ``onCreate``. Но на всякий случай для активности, которая вызывает диалог, тоже попробовал добавить (ну мало-ли), но выдало ошибку.

Comment: Стоп. А вы, когда писали "Если используете Dialog:", имели ввиду ``AlertDialog``?

Comment: @bukashka101 >У диалогов вроде же нет 'onCreate' если Вы расширяли `DialogFragment` то есть такой метод! вот его переопределите и засуньте туда эту строку

Comment: @bukashka101 >имели ввиду AlertDialog - Dialog и имел ввиду...

Comment: Заработало! В ``onCreate``!

Answer (score 3):

У меня работает такой вариант.

Activity диалогового окна:

```
public class ActivityLikeADialogue extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOk;
    TextView textDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_dialogue);

        textDialog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_dialog) ;
        textDialog.setText("Hello, I'm the dialog text!");

        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_dialog);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityLikeADialogue"
            android:theme="@style/AlertDialogNoTitle">
</activity>
```

Style:

```
<style name="AlertDialogNoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

---

**UPD:**
Полный пример на [гитхаб](https://github.com/vmarch/CustomDialog) залил.

---

**UPD2:** 
А вот так оно смотрится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло добавить

supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

перед

setContentView(R.layout.MyDialogActivity);